# Receiving discord.js slash command parameters

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently trying to make a calculation using parameters input via a slash command. Putting them in works fine, however I do not know how to actually retrieve them. the current code yields an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')` which has me quite confused, as the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=get) shows that said function should exist and be exactly what I'm looking for.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('manacost')
        .setDescription('Calculates the ´soul spawn cost using your inputs')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('health')
                .setDescription('The amount of health your soul has. Supports k=1000...')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('damage')
                .setDescription('The amount of damage your soul has. Supports k=1000...')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addIntegerOption(option =>
            option.setName('breeze')
                .setDescription('The amount of breeze you have.(0-80)')
                .setRequired(false)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
        let hp = interaction.options.get('health');
        let dmg = interaction.option.get('damage');
        let b =  interaction.option.get('breeze');
        console.log({hp, dmg, b});
        await interaction.reply({content: hp, dmg, b});
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction options can be found using `interaction.option.getString()` or `interaction.option.getInteger()`. Also in your Code you have mixed up `interaction.options` and `interaction.option`. You should only use `interaction.options`.

That means your code has to change from

```js
let hp = interaction.options.get('health');
let dmg = interaction.option.get('damage');
let b =  interaction.option.get('breeze');
```

to

```js
let hp = interaction.options.getString('health');
let dmg = interaction.options.getString('damage');
let b =  interaction.options.getInteger('breeze');
```

You should take a look at [this](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#command-options) post from the discord.js guide for more information and a look at the other option types.